# SharePoint 2010 Calendar NewForm.aspx

Tags: calendar

I need to check if the Recurrence checkbox is checked by JAvaScript code and if it is checked I require the user to provide an end date. So far the following has not worked:

```
 var cntrl5 = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("INPUT","BooleanField","Recurrence");
  if (cntrl5.Checked ==true)
  {
       alert('the control is found');

  }
```

Any idea how I can write code to check if the recurrence checkbox has been checked?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with jQuery.

```
if($("TABLE.ms-formtable>TBODY>TR:eq(6)").attr('checked')) {
    if (inp.val().length > 0) {
    // do something
    }
} else {
     //nothing
}
```